# Making one bitmap (image) out of 3 pictureboxes (that do not contain images)

Tags: c#, image, copy, picturebox

In my form, I have 3 pictureboxes. These 3 pictureboxes have paint events that draw on their surface. Now I want to assemble the contents from the 3 pictureboxes to one bitmap, so I can copy the complete thing to the clipboard.

However, I'm quite stumped. I can't seem to get the content of the pictureboxes copied to an image (because I'm using the paint event).

My code looks like this :

```
pbPictureBox1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.graphics.whatever;  // there's a _lot_ of drawing happening here.
}

pbPictureBox2_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.graphics.whatever;  // there's a _lot_ of drawing happening here.
}

pbPictureBox3_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.graphics.whatever;  // there's a _lot_ of drawing happening here.
}
```

Now, I want to copy the contents of all my pictureboxes to a bitmap, so I can copy it to the clipboard. I can create a new bitmap with the correct size, and copy it to the clipboard. But whatever I do, I can't seem to copy the contents of my pboxes to the bitmap.

```
Bitmap ClipboardBitmap = new Bitmap(correctwidth, correctheight);
// here, I want to copy the contents of pbox1 to some position 0,y of the bitmap
// here, I want to copy the contents of pbox2 to some position x,0 of the bitmap
// here, I want to copy the contents of pbox3 to some position x,y of the bitmap
Clipboard.SetImage(ClipboardBitmap);
```

A while ago, I was drawing on my pictureboxes by first creating an image, drawing on the image and then assign it to the picturebox. That was too slow however (there's a *lot* of painting going on), so I had to resort to the _paint event. But now I can't get my graphics out of the picturebox anymore. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After messing for 3 hours and not getting it to work, ofcourse I figure it out in 10 minutes after finally deciding to post the question..

Here's how to do it ;

```
            // make new bitmap
            Bitmap ClipboardBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

            // copy content of pb1 to position 0, y of bitmap
            Rectangle pb1Area = new Rectangle(0, y, labelwidth, labelheigth);
            pb1.DrawToBitmap(ClipboardBitmap, pb1Area);

            // same for pb2 and pb3...

            // copy bitmap to clipboard
            Clipboard.SetImage(ClipboardBitmap);
```